# Get parent layerX in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I have one parent div and one child div and I want to retrieve parent layerX when mouse is move on child region
When I do event.layerX on mousemove event, it gives me child layerX value but I want parent layerX value.

```
<div id='parentDiv'>
    <div id='childDiv'></div>
</div>
```

And in javascript I do

```
$('#childDiv').onmousemove=function(e){
    var layerValue;
    layerValue=  e.layerX;
}
```

But It not work. It gives me child layerX. I also do

```
$(e.target).parent().e.layerX
```

But it also gives Error.

Thanks.